# ¿Como leer un csv grande en PySpark?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark

Estoy intentando leer un fichero csv en un dataframe utilizando PySpark. El problema es que el csv tiene 6596 filas x 98942 columnas y me sale un error que dice:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o28.csv.
> : com.univocity.parsers.common.TextParsingException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - 20480
> Hint: Number of columns processed may have exceeded limit of 20480 columns. Use settings.setMaxColumns(int) to define the maximum number of columns your input can have

el código de mi programa es:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.Builder().appName("read_csv").getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.csv("dirección_de_mi_fichero.csv", header="true",sep=",")
df.show()
```

¿Será que debo usar otra estructua que no sea un dataframe para leer el fichero?

Comment: Probaste con aplicar la solución que te ofrece el mensaje de error??? Lee esta parte del error que te puede dar una pista de que hacer: `Use settings.setMaxColumns(int) to define the maximum number of columns your input can have`

Comment: No, realmente no he probado, en parte porque no sé cómo hacerlo. Pero el problema es que ese fichero csv debe crecer mucho más. Las columnas pueden llegar a ser millones. Por eso no creo que esa sea una solución factible. Realmente lo que quiero es ver si hay otra forma de leer el fichero.

Comment: Esto (en el sitio en ingles) responde a tu pregunta? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39184929/how-to-import-csv-files-with-massive-column-count-into-apache-spark-2-0

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me ha servido de mucho su respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de leer los comentarios y revisar el enlace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39184929/how-to-import-csv-files-with-massive-column-count-into-apache-spark-2-0 del sitio en ingles pude dar con la respuesta. La dejo aquí por si alguien hace una búsqueda similar en el sitio no tenga que ir al sitio en inglés a encontrar la respuesta.

```
df = spark.read.option("maxColumns", 100000).csv("dirección_de_mi_fichero.csv", header="true",sep=",")
```